# Problems with using Kenwheeler slick carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I am trying to initialise and be able to use the carousel from the website
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. I have exactly followed all the instruction but I still cant seem to be getting it to work. I really dont know what I am doing wrong. Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Now Amazing Webpage</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="your-class">
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
    <div>your content</div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">







    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.your-class').slick({
            setting-name: setting-value
        });
    });

    $('.your-class').slick();



 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Various potential issues, but if you aren't going to have any settings then don't include the block with `setting-name: setting-value` (which is a placeholder and will throw a JS error if you just leave it as is).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.your-class').slick({
        // setting-name: setting-value
    });
});
```

Also, if running this locally, the jQuery links probably won't work, so you can use the full links instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Check your browser's error console if that doesn't fully fix it.

Comment: Yes that does work but since I am using a foundation framework to impelement the carousel it doesnt seem to be working with them which is a problem