# Trouble adding Slick Carasel from kenwheeler to Foundation template

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, carousel, slick.js

I am having trouble adding the Slick Carousel to my foundation template. I followed the instructions from here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
and 
read the answeres to the question here: [Problems with using Kenwheeler slick carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426118/problems-with-using-kenwheeler-slick-carousel), and made the requested changes.

But, my carousel is still not working.

I put the Slick folder referenced in my local folder.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>**** | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>

        <!--slick css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
                   <div class="your-class">
                      <div>your content</div>
                      <div>your content</div>
                      <div>your content</div>
                    </div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.your-class').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      fade: true,
      slide: '> div',
      cssEase: 'linear'
});
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you have shared is the exact code you have used then close the script tag for jquery-migrate.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

This should help. 
I'm not sure if the following is valid in your jquery snippet.

```
slick:'< div',
```

Please check that too.